# Exception : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException OraclePreparedStatement

Tags: java, prepared-statement, oracle12c

I am getting an exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException calling the method executeBatch:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:11107)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:244)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
```

here is the code:

```
// list with 2500 entries   
for (CMInfo cm : list) {
    if (cm != null) {
        int i = 1;
        stmt.setTimestamp(i++, cm.getDate());
        stmt.setString(i++, cm.getId());
        stmt.setString(i++, cm.getName());
        stmt.setString(i++, cm.getCMap()); // +/- 3000 characteres
        stmt.setString(i++, cm.getCMapIds()); // +/- 2000 characteres
        stmt.setTimestamp(i++, cm.getLastUpdate());
        stmt.setString(i++, cm.getInstance());
        stmt.setString(i++, cm.getStatus());
        stmt.setString(i++, cm.getProcessingID());
        stmt.setInt(i++, cm.getCounter());
        stmt.setInt(i++, cm.getPriority());
        stmt.addBatch();
    }
}

stmt.executeBatch();
connection.commit();
```

Comment: *"list with 2500 entries"* Are you sure? Because I believe I've seen error like this when calling `executeBatch()` without calling `addBatch()` first. Some drivers fail when trying to execute an empty batch.

Comment: What is `OraclePreparedStatement` doing on line 11107? That might give you a clue.

Comment: if (this.batchRowsUpdatedArray != null)
              {
                assert (this.batchRowsUpdatedArray.length == this.currentRank);
                System.arraycopy(this.batchRowsUpdatedArray, 0, localObject1, this.firstRowInBatch, this.currentRank); // line 11107
              }

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar exception after switching to Oracle 12c from Oracle 11g while still using ojdbc7.jar driver package.
Updating the driver solved the problem for me.
I suggest you try ojdbc8.jar driver package available at:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html

It does require Java 8 though.